# How to calculate the exponent/power value (how much of the power) i.e. 'n' in c++?

Tags: c++, math, exponential

How can we calculate the value/degree of power exponent of a certain number?

I mean if it's like a^n = b, then how can we calculate n?

For example assume that a = 2 and b = 8, then how can we calculate that n = 3? Is there any special function?

Comment: it's called logarithm!

Comment: Check out the common math functions available: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math

Comment: yeah thank you but i already know you can do it using logarithmic functions in mathematics. If you don't mind could you refer me to a source where this question is implemented already?

Comment: For base 2 and b in a floating point type you can also use the frexp function in math.h/cmath to find the exponent of the closest integer power of 2.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please I can't find what I'm looking for there. I've had checked that before.

Comment: Questions about high-school algebra are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you know about logs, why didn't just ask for an implementation of the log function? A simple googling would be more helpful though

Comment: What happened to mathematics education?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the same logarithmic functions here too. Include `cmath`.

**In-code**

```
.
. 
cout << log(8) / log(3) << endl;
.
.
```

**Output**

```
   .
   .
   .
...3...
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Thank you! Very simple and elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::log`. Example from the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) page:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double base = 2.0;
    double arg  = 8.0;
    double result = std::log(arg) / std::log(base);

    std::cout << result << '\n'; // prints 3
}
```

More to learn at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).

Comment: Note for OP: this uses the fact that if we write `2` and `8` as `e^p` and `e^q` respectively, then we try to solve `(e^p)^x = e^q` --> `(e^x)^p = e^q` -->  `e^x = e^(q/p)`  --> `x = q/p`. This works for any base, not just `e`; C++ comes with built-in logs to base `e` and base `10`; you can find log to any other base using this trick.

Comment: @Danvil Oh! Didn't checked that Sorry

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the logarithm of b to the base a (at least we call it that in german).

C++ example:

```
#include <cmath>       /* log */

int main ()
{
  int a = 2;
  int b = 8;
  float n = log(b) / log(a); // 3
}
```

Comment: Header is called `cmath` in C++. Btw you exactly duplicated my answer...

Comment: Nah, it was kind of at the same time but you were a little faster...

Comment: What a retard I am that was so easy!